# Why nominalize words instead of using them directly as verbs, adverbs or adjectives?

Tags: etymology, nouns, nominalization, relational-nouns

My question is focused particularly on verbs ending in て form nominalised with の and adverbs ending in く also nominalised with の:

> かねての instead of かねる
>
> 近くの instead of 近くある/近い

My understanding of nouns (no-adjectives) made from the て form of verbs is that they mean "after-having-done" as noun qualifier. For example, 兼ねる means "to do two things at the same time", so 兼ねて/予て would mean "after doing/having done something at the same time".

I think this is similar to how な is used for nouns. (Original meaning: I thought the function of の was similar to な.)

On the other hand, I don't understand the need for くの. I know that words such as 近く are used as nouns, and I also understand that 近い can't be used at the beginning of a sentence, as discussed in [this goo article](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2848163.html) (the reason why I talked about relational nouns was because 1. One of the answers for the question found in the goo article talked about の nominalised nouns usually having a trait of range in them, like long to short, etc. However, I am not sure nor do I think that relational nouns are the proper word to describe them) However, why not simply using 近い directly attached to a noun instead of 近くの? Why does 近い need to become 近く?

In short, why do some verbs or adjectives have and need their noun forms that come from their continuative form (て) or adverbial form (く)? Why do they need to become [relational nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_noun)?

Comment: What "goo article" are you talking about? I'm not aware of any restriction on putting 近【ちか】い at the start of a sentence, like 「近【ちか】い所【ところ】は便利【べんり】です」 ("nearby places are convenient").

Comment: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2848163.html

Comment: Could you add the question in your native language, besides English?

Comment: English is my native language and sometimes native English speakers are not fluent in English and I just so happen to be one of them

Comment: Related: [lexicalized adverbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40551/32952)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. So, just to point a few items that make your first sentence so confusing. What is "()" supposed to mean? and "if- or"? and "ror"? Can you break the first sentence down to shorter sentences?

Comment: My understanding of nouns (no-adjectives) from the て form of verbs is that the verb they come from is conjugated in the て form to represent the hypothetical nature of the verb (e.g if blank) or after/when the verb happens, and then made into a noun

Comment: ror is a typo of for

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I suppose the following may help https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/89159/45489 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83691/45489 In short, there are a number of ways to make a noun form of a word, 連用形の名詞化 (*nominalization of masu/te stem*) is one of them, and it's a word-by-word matter whether a word admits the tyep of nominalization.

Comment: Why 近い/近くの are used differently is just another matter (that has nothing to do with te-form or nominalization). You can post another question if that's the main question.

Comment: I edited your post to reflect your question more clearly, please feel free to rollback if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for that! - very very very very incredibly extraordinarily cool and epic

Comment: Also, while editing your original question, I didn't really understand 1) why you think it's similar to な for nouns, and 2) why you think nominalization turns these words into relational nouns (aren't relational nouns simply a completely different thing than nominalization in general?). Could you expand on 1) and 2)? You can edit your own question directly.

Comment: Just as the English word `adjective` is a noun even though it looks *like* an adjective, 近く is now a full-fledged noun even though it looks like a form of an i-adjective. You have to remember such exceptions.